# How do I move friends from one list to another on Facebook

Tags: facebook, friend-list

To approach the functionality of Google+ circles, I'd like to move all friends from one Facebook list to another. For example, I'd like to move most of the people from my list for where I work (smart list) to Acquaintances, where I can set that list to have less access to my profile.

How can I select a sub-set of friends from one list and move them to another in Facebook?

**edit** http://www.friendmanager.org/ looks interesting, but it only takes 3 lists (general, close friends, acquaintances). I can't find a way to move more than one friend at a time (not fun when you have 400+).

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but *how* exactly can you move one Google circle to another? I see no such option. Edit, okay you can drag and select all members of the circle

Comment: @phwd In Google+, you click on the circle and it becomes an active list of users. Then you select the users using the lasso or other means, and move to another circle.

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://www.circlehack.com/ made as an experiment by some Facebook engineers.

The source is here if ever the site goes down https://github.com/voloko/facebook-circles

Comment: Works in IE9 (Chrome gave me some endless loop trying to get permissions, but maybe because I have an adblocker and NotScripts).  Sadly, the only multi-select "source" list is the entire list of friends - one can't select multiples from pre-defined lists. I want to choose all from my smart-list and move to acquaintances, for example. But this is better than nothing. Also, I'd vote you up, if I had the rep to do it!